# NSNotification issues when opening app from another app

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter

I have associated a file type with my App, so it can open text files.

I have no issues when my app is in the background, and I open the text file from another app - the file is read and is displayed.

However, if my app is not in the background, and gets loaded for the first time via the "open in" pathway from another app that can read text files. The notification is not received - and thus the text file is not read.

I am creating the notification in the app delegate when a file it read.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool
```

The first view controller in my app is registered for the notification in viewDidLoad.

I believe the reason is simple, the App Delegate posts the notification - but the receiver in my first view controller is not registered so my notification is  lost in the matrix.

So, whats the best way to overcome this problem ? Maybe delay the notification dispatch for a few seconds ?

Just for reference, this is a [good tutorial](http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/stevez/archive/2013/03/04/associate-a-file-type-with-your-ios-application.aspx) on setting up the basic process of opening files in your app

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To keep it simple,

I just delayed the call by one second to give the first view controller time to register itself

```
    let timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "postAfterDelay:", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```